# SED: how to pull out version string

Tags: version-control, sed, version

I would like to use sed to pull out the version number from the command:

```
svnversion --version
```

Which gives output like:

```
svnversion, version 1.6.2 (r37639)
   compiled May 10 2009, 12:41:21

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).
```

And after processing with sed, I'd like just:

```
1.6.2
```

So far, I have this monstrosity (due to my ignorance):

```
svnversion --version | sed s/[\wa-zA-Z//\(\):,]*//g | sed 's/[ ]//' | sed 's/[ ]//' | sed 's/[ ][0-9 ./n/-]*//'
```

I'm sure there is a simple elegant solution that an expert can provide easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this isn't using sed, but based upon your output this is easier.

```
svnversion --version | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

If you have perl available...

```
svnversion --version | perl -lne 'print $1 if /version (\d+.\d+.\d+)/'
```

Comment: Yep: UNIX command lines are all about using the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
svnversion --version | sed -n '/version/ s/.*version \([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\) .*/\1/p'
```

It says:

- `-n` **---** *Don't automatically print output.*
- `/version/` **---** *On lines that include the string "version",*
- `s/` - *substitute for what's*
- `.*version` and `.*` **---** *between [a sequence of zero or more of any character, the string "version",  a space] and [a space, a sequence of zero or more of any character],*
- `\(...\)` **---** *capturing*
- `[0-9]\+` **---** *a sequence of one or more digits*
- `\.` **---** *followed by a literal period*
- *then more digits and periods,*
- `/\1/` **---** *what was captured in the first (and only, in this case) set of parentheses*
- `p` **---** *and explicitly print it.*

Because automatic printing is suppressed and only the line that includes "version" is selected, the other lines are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do it w/o sed:
`svnversion --version | head -1 | cut -d" " -f3`